# Issue with Spring profiles and my properties files

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry, properties-file

I am trying **to activate one set of properties files for one Spring profile** and another set for another Spring profile as follows:

```
<beans profile="cloud">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/cloud/*.properties" />
</beans>

<beans profile="default">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/default/*.properties" />
</beans>
```

I have the corresponding and appropriate directory structure in my `src/main/resources` folder.

I have a simple `@Value("${application.url}")` in one of my services and I systematically get the following error:

> Error creating bean with name 'mailerServiceImpl': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.Be anCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private java.lang.String
>   com.kadjoukor.service.MailerServiceImpl.websiteContext; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
>   placeholder 'application.url' in string value "${application.url}"

Note that I have tried adding a `spring.profiles.active` `init-param` to my web.xml. It doesn't make any difference...

I am not sure what I am getting wrong. Can anyone please provide advice?

**EDIT 1**: Could it matter that the above snippets of configuration are **located at the bottom of the configuration file**?

**EDIT 2**: Here is the output of my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" metadata-complete="true">
    <display-name>kadjoukor</display-name>
    <description>Roo generated kadjoukor application</description>
    <!-- Enable escaping of form submission contents -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml classpath:META-INF/cloud/cloudfoundry-auto-reconfiguration-context.xml</param-value></context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Handles Spring requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>kadjoukor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml classpath:META-INF/cloud/cloudfoundry-auto-reconfiguration-context.xml</param-value></init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>kadjoukor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout><!-- TODO -->
    </session-config>
<context-param><param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name><param-value>org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.spring.CloudApplicationContextInitializer</param-value></context-param></web-app>
```

and here is the contents of the `WEB-INF/libs` directory:

```
activation-1.1.1.jar                     67.8K
antlr-2.7.6.jar                         433.0K
aopalliance-1.0.jar                       4.4K
asm-3.3.1.jar                            42.6K
aspectjrt-1.7.0.RC1.jar                 113.5K
aspectjweaver-1.7.0.RC1.jar               1.7M
auto-reconfiguration-0.6.5.jar          693.3K
cglib-2.2.2.jar                         280.5K
cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar                   319.3K
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar             226.6K
commons-codec-1.5.jar                    71.4K
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar           561.9K
commons-dbcp-1.3.jar                    145.3K
commons-digester-2.1.jar                192.2K
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar             58.2K
commons-io-2.1.jar                      159.3K
commons-lang3-3.1.jar                   308.4K
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar                37.1K
commons-pool-1.5.6.jar                   98.1K
dom4j-1.6.1.jar                         306.5K
ehcache-core-2.6.0.jar                    1.3M
flexjson-2.1.jar                         79.2K
guava-11.0.2.jar                          1.6M
hamcrest-core-1.1.jar                    74.8K
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar      69.6K
hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar            3.0M
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.9.Final.jar     416.3K
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar     100.3K
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar     358.0K
httpclient-4.1.2.jar                    344.0K
httpcore-4.1.2.jar                      177.0K
imgscalr-lib-4.2.jar                     27.2K
jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar              226.7K
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9.jar            762.0K
java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar                  18.1K
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar                 618.5K
javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar                 643.9K
javax.inject-1.jar                        2.4K
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar                 16.9K
jets3t-0.9.0.jar                        527.1K
jmimemagic-0.1.2.jar                     44.5K
joda-time-2.1.jar                       557.1K
jsr305-1.3.9.jar                         32.2K
jstl-api-1.2.jar                         29.8K
jstl-impl-1.2.jar                       382.8K
jta-1.1.jar                              14.7K
junit-dep-4.8.2.jar                     213.2K
log4j-1.2.16.jar                        470.2K
mail-1.4.3.jar                          451.3K
mysema-commons-lang-0.2.4.jar            11.8K
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar         771.4K
ognl-3.0.5.jar                          222.5K
oro-2.0.8.jar                            63.7K
prettytime-1.0.8.Final.jar               65.4K
querydsl-core-2.9.0.jar                 367.3K
querydsl-jpa-2.9.0.jar                   93.3K
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar                      25.4K
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar                   9.5K
spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar            327.0K
spring-aspects-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar         68.2K
spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar          590.6K
spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar        834.0K
spring-context-support-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar     124.1K
spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar           842.8K
spring-data-commons-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar     215.0K
spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar       129.8K
spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar     189.2K
spring-jdbc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar           391.6K
spring-js-resources-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar       4.3M
spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar            383.0K
spring-security-acl-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar      77.7K
spring-security-config-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar     198.9K
spring-security-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar     332.1K
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar      20.3K
spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar     245.2K
spring-social-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar     113.7K
spring-social-facebook-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar     117.2K
spring-social-web-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar      18.0K
spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar             235.3K
spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar            609.7K
spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar         621.0K
thymeleaf-2.0.14.jar                    677.9K
thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-1.0.0-beta3-SNAPSHOT.jar      46.7K
thymeleaf-spring3-2.0.14.jar            161.9K
tiles-api-2.2.2.jar                      35.1K
tiles-core-2.2.2.jar                    157.2K
tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar                      49.6K
tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar                  58.3K
tiles-template-2.2.2.jar                 23.9K
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar              46.3K
xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar                      1.1M
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar                     106.8K
xmlParserAPIs-2.0.2.jar                  76.6K
```

Comment: Can you confirm that when you move the propery-placeholder thing out of a <beans profile="">, it does work (ie the location is good and the placeholder mechanism works)

Comment: Yes I do confirm the above.

Comment: OK. What kind of application do you have, is it standalone or a webapp? The cloud profile being activated works in most situations, but not all (see eg https://cloudfoundry.atlassian.net/browse/CF-132). Can you please use "vmc files xxx" to have a look at your web.xml and contents of WEB-INF/lib to see that the former has been modified and the latter contains an additional jar compared to what you built.

Comment: @ebottard: Thanks. I can see any additional jar... I have included the result of the command for good measure as well as the content of the web.xml.

Comment: @ebottard: Can you please tell me what additional jar you are referring to? How can I add it?

Comment: I was referring to auto-reconfiguration-0.6.5.jar. You don't have to add it yourself, this is done for you. This jar contains the classes that do the autoconf magic, so I wanted to make sure that it was there. See also the very last line of web.xml which was added at staging time. Hmmm, this is getting more and more complicated to diagnose. Do you have access to a micro Cloud Foundry VM? If so, you could plug a debugger there and see what happens/does not happen.

Comment: Also, in the logs of your app, at startup, you should see information about profiles being activated/not activated. What do you get there?

Comment: I do have VMC set up on my machine. Is that what you are referring to by "micro cloud foundry VM"? As far as the startup logs are concerned, I see no information about profiles either being activated or not being activated...

Comment: No, I'm referring to this: https://micro.cloudfoundry.com/ this is a full Cloud Foundry distribution but packed in one single VM that you can run on your laptop. This allows remote debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the https://cloudfoundry.atlassian.net/browse/CF-132 bug, in order to have the cloud profile work, you would need a ContextLoaderInitializer. So I would suggest you to create a context file, even leave it empty if you have to, to make the cloud profile work.